# SQL using Union All solution required

Tags: oracle, coalesce, union-all

[I have 5 tables which are set up at SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3c9bc/18)

I need assistance in refining the below query. Currently it gives me "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Db - Oracle 11.x

```
sum(CRED) - sum(DEB) of 'Insurer' records only; group by pol.SP_NUM

select sp_num as pol_#, 
(coalesce (sum(
(
select     sum(Q.AMTQ) AS INSD 
from     S_INVOICE debit
,         S_ASSET pol
,         S_QUOTE_ITEM Q 
where     debit.FN_ACCNT_ID        =    pol.row_id
and     pol.x_quote_id            =    Q.row_id 
and     debit.DEBIT_TYPE        =    'Insurer'
and     debit.CO_ID is null
UNION ALL
select     sum(QXM.AMTQXM) AS INSD 
from     S_INVOICE debit
,         S_ASSET pol
,         S_QUOTE_ITEM_XM QXM 
where     debit.FN_ACCNT_ID        =    pol.row_id 
and     debit.DEBIT_TYPE        =    'Insurer'
and     debit.CO_ID                =    QXM.ROW_ID
)
  ),0) - 
  coalesce (sum(
  (
    select     sum(Q.AMTQ) AS INSC 
    from     S_SRC_PAYMENT credit
    ,         S_ASSET pol
    ,        S_QUOTE_ITEM Q 
    where     credit.ASSET_ID            =    pol.row_id
    and     pol.x_quote_id            =    Q.row_id 
    and     credit.CG_DEDN_TYPE_CD    =    'Insurer'
    and     credit.CO_ID is null
    UNION ALL
    select     sum(QXM.AMTQXM) AS INSC 
    from     S_SRC_PAYMENT credit
    ,         S_ASSET pol
    ,         S_QUOTE_ITEM_XM QXM 
    where     credit.asset_id            =    pol.row_id
    and     credit.CG_DEDN_TYPE_CD    =    'Insurer'
    and     credit.CO_ID            =    QXM.ROW_ID
    )
  ),0)
) as NP
from s_asset
group by sp_num;
```

Expected O/P:

```
sum(cred) - sum(deb) = (412) - (63.1) = 348.9
```

Comment: Do you not have a text editor which shows you unbalanced parentheses?

Comment: issue was relating to the coalesce syntax being incorrect. This has been rectified. Current error is "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The revised query I came up with is:

```
WITH CREDITS AS (SELECT SP_NUM, SUM(INSC) AS TOTAL_CREDITS
                   FROM (select pol.SP_NUM, Q.AMTQ AS INSC 
                           from S_SRC_PAYMENT credit,
                                S_ASSET pol,
                                S_QUOTE_ITEM Q 
                           where credit.ASSET_ID = pol.row_id and
                                 pol.x_quote_id = Q.row_id and
                                 credit.CG_DEDN_TYPE_CD = 'Insurer' and
                                 credit.CO_ID is null
                         UNION ALL
                         select pol.SP_NUM, QXM.AMTQXM AS INSC
                           from S_SRC_PAYMENT credit,
                                S_ASSET pol,
                                S_QUOTE_ITEM_XM QXM 
                           where credit.asset_id = pol.row_id and
                                 credit.CG_DEDN_TYPE_CD = 'Insurer' and
                                 credit.CO_ID = QXM.ROW_ID)
                   GROUP BY SP_NUM),
     DEBITS AS (SELECT SP_NUM, SUM(INSD) AS TOTAL_DEBITS
                  FROM (select pol.SP_NUM, Q.AMTQ AS INSD 
                          from S_INVOICE debit,
                               S_ASSET pol,
                               S_QUOTE_ITEM Q 
                          where debit.FN_ACCNT_ID = pol.row_id and
                                pol.x_quote_id = Q.row_id and
                                debit.DEBIT_TYPE = 'Insurer' and
                                debit.CO_ID is null
                          UNION ALL
                          select pol.SP_NUM, QXM.AMTQXM AS INSD 
                            from S_INVOICE debit,
                                 S_ASSET pol,
                                 S_QUOTE_ITEM_XM QXM 
                            where debit.FN_ACCNT_ID = pol.row_id and
                                  debit.DEBIT_TYPE = 'Insurer' and
                                  debit.CO_ID = QXM.ROW_ID)
                  GROUP BY SP_NUM)
SELECT COALESCE(c.SP_NUM, d.SP_NUM) AS POL_#,
       COALESCE(TOTAL_CREDITS, 0) - COALESCE(TOTAL_DEBITS, 0) AS NP
  FROM CREDITS c
  FULL OUTER JOIN DEBITS d
    ON d.SP_NUM = c.SP_NUM;
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3c9bc/41)

The basic problem was that the internal queries (here pulled out as CTE's) were summing the INSC and INSD values, but weren't preserving the SP_NUM (policy number) as part of the summation (i.e. there was no GROUP BY). Also, because I don't know your data and thus couldn't be certain that each policy number would have at least a credit or a debit I made it a FULL OUTER JOIN. If you can be certain that there will always be either a credit or a debit to a policy number you could put that CTE first in the final SELECT and the LEFT OUTER JOIN the other table. In any case, this works.

Best of luck.

Comment: thank u Bob, ideally there should be at least one credit & one debit record per policy (I see that you have very smartly inferred Pol# to be Policy Number) but there are always defects in data...so ur solution works like a charm. Thanks again, especially for responding on the weekend.